# OpenCV DNN, Import .pb file from tensorflow Assertion Failed error: scaleMat.type() == CV_32FC1 in function 'populateNet'

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, opencv3.1

I was trying to import a frozen (and optimized using tensorflow.python.tools.optimize_for_inference ) pb "optimized.pb" file using

```
cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow("optimized.pb")
```

This resulted in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "opencv.py", line 4, in <module>
    net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow("optimized.pb")
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.3) /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/tensorflow/tf_importer.cpp:1380: error: (-215:Assertion failed) scaleMat.type() == CV_32FC1 in function 'populateNet'
```

The model included transpose convolution layers. However the error disappears when I do not include any deconvolution layers.

Can anyone help me understand and correct this error?

Comment: Did you correct this error? I'm using OpenCV4.5.3 and still get the same error.

Comment: Nope. I was not able to get it working and I moved on.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this error in my network by replace 
up8 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), interpolation='bilinear')(conv7)
to
up8 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv7)
It looks like my opencv(version 3.4.6) is not supported bilinear interpolation in UpSampling2D layer.