# How can you know the layers supported by dnn?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, opencv, keras

I have implemented a neural network in Tensorflow. The network is quite simple and only uses Cov2D, MaxPooling and UpSampling2D.

The specs are:

- Python: 3.7
- Tensorflow: 1.14.0
- Keras: 2.2.4-tf
- Ubuntu: 18.04.4 LTS

Once the network was trained I have converted it to .pb, to be able to read it from OpenCV and C++ on Windows PC.

- Windws 10
- Opencv: 3.4.0

But appear the next error when I read the NN on C++:

```cpp
cv::dnn::Net MODEL = cv::dnn::readNetFromTensorflow("SLI_model_64.pb");

up_sampling2d/Shape:Shape(conv2d_5/Relu)
out_type:[ ]
T:0
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (Unknown layer type Shape in op up_sampling2d/Shape) in cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_v3::`anonymous-namespace'::TFImporter::populateNet, file c:\sdk\opencv\3.4.0\sources\modules\dnn\src\tensorflow\tf_importer.cpp, line 1487
```

As I have been able to find out, the C ++ version does not support Upsamplig. Are you agree? How could I check?

Comment: Can you comment on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53570257/opencv-dnn-import-pb-file-from-tensorflow-assertion-failed-error-scalemat-typ

Answer (score 0):

I can not view the layers supported by opencv dnn, but if update opencv to 4.2 the problem dissapear. Most likely, opecv 3.4 does not support UpSampling and this has been updated for opencv 4.2.

Comment: I am using OpenCV(4.5.3) and get this error: net = cv2.dnn.readNet(path2frozengraph)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) /tmp/pip-req-build-tjxnaiom/opencv/modules/dnn/src/tensorflow/tf_importer.cpp:1464: error: (-215:Assertion failed) scaleMat.type() == CV_32FC1 in function 'parseMul'